# Flask App Getting AH01630: client denied by server configuration error in Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

Getting 403 Forbidden when attempting to send requests to my Flask app.

Finding a lot of examples of this error online but none of the solutions work for me so far.

Error from the apache error log file:

```
AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/MyTinyURL/webtool.wsgi
```

Here is my VirtualHost.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName MY_SERVER_NAME
  DocumentRoot /opt/MyTinyURL

  WSGIDaemonProcess webtool user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/opt/MyTinyURL/
  WSGIScriptAlias / "/opt/MyTinyURL/webtool.wsgi"

  <Directory "/opt/MyTinyUrl">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    WSGIProcessGroup webtool
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNIX file path names are case sensitive. The path used with `WSGIScriptAlias` doesn't match that used in the `Directory` directive.

Cleaning up a few other issues with things that aren't needed, try using:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName MY_SERVER_NAME

  # XXX Bad practice to set DocumentRoot to be directory
  # where your code is. Comment out WSGIScriptAlias and
  # people could download your source code.
  # DocumentRoot /opt/MyTinyURL

  # XXX Don't need user/group as the default to Apache user.
  WSGIDaemonProcess webtool threads=5 home=/opt/MyTinyURL/
  WSGIScriptAlias / "/opt/MyTinyURL/webtool.wsgi"

  # XXX You had MyTinyUrl and not MyTinyURL.
  <Directory "/opt/MyTinyURL">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    WSGIProcessGroup webtool
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    # XXX Script reloading is the default option.
    # WSGIScriptReloading On
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well I certainly feel dumb! This does solve the issue! And I really appreciate the security suggestion too :)